# Database in travis setted, but application cannot connect

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, travis-ci

I'm developing a web-app using spring framework.
Here is my application-properites:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springboot
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=
                                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect
```

And here it is my travis.yml configuration on github:

```
services:
  - mongodb
  - mysql

before_install:
  - mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db_example;"
  - mysql -e "CREATE USER 'springboot'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 
   'password'";
  - mysql -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_example.* TO 'springboot'@'%' 
    WITH GRANT OPTION;"
  - mysql -e "CREATE TABLE db_example.sql_grid(id int PRIMARY KEY, 
    matrix TEXT, n int);"
```

If i set up the database using docker in such way locally, the build passes. If the build is done by travis, it fails due to a UnableToAcquireJDBCConnection exception. Why?

Comment: provide full stacktrace.